# How do I scan all ubuntu source code? I have downloaded & extracted all 5 source dvd iso images

Tags: iso, dvd, tar, source-code

I have downloaded and extracted all 5 source DVD iso images (`ubuntu-19.10.1-src-*`). There is no useful `README`; `README.diskdefines` is useless to me. I guess that the source code is embedded inside a gazillion `tar` files e.g. `ubuntu-19.10.1-src-1/pool/main/a/accountservice/accountservice_0.6.55.orig.tar.xz`.

I now want to scan Ubuntu for some code (using `mlocate` maybe), that displays the '`Oh no! Something has gone wrong`' image, as it's popping up.

How do I extract all the source from the extracted DVD images? Is there a script? Or where can I find non-compressed source?

## EDIT2

I have fixed the problem from which this question arose, but I still think that it's a reasonable question - how can I view all the source without manually extracting from each tar?

## /EDIT2

Comment: I'm trying to find why my fresh install of 19.10 suddenly failed. I have tried working from the outside-in ("why did this pop up?") and getting no response. So now I'll try working from the inside-out -  scanning source to see why this message is popping up. My question is how to scan the source that seems compressed into a gazillion tarballs. I am also adding WHY I want to scan the source; I have often seen people post about how to do something, and responders ask "Why do you want to do that?" Well, I add that to save someone asking. It's possible that there's a better way to achieve my goal.

Comment: I might see 2 flaws in your method: the text string is likely inside a text file holding strings since text is going to be translated at some point.  Next: it will be inside software that might get called by a dozen other programs. Besides that: these errors get logged. Why not find the log file? It will point to the file the error originates from. Login into a tty and use command line for it. That is why it is there.

Comment: _“I have often seen people post about how to do something, and responders ask "Why do you want to do that?"”_ Such responders generally try to avoid an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Rinzwind has written in [their comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209365/how-do-i-scan-all-ubuntu-source-code-i-have-downloaded-extracted-all-5-source#comment2030502_1209365) what it means in your case.

Comment: @Rinzwind "Why not find the log file" You make it sound like there's only one. There are about a dozen, and the one I needed wouldn't be found if I searched *.log (it was in syslog). Oh, and there are journals too. Even when searching syslog, scanning for 'error' wasn't very useful, as there were so many of them. And several days went by before someone pointed me to which log file to try; this question/request was already in. Adding a 'reason' string to the "Oh no" message would make life easier.

Comment: "There are about a dozen"  each with a name indentifying them.  Why are you being so difficult? Make the system crash, go to /var/log/, do `ls -ltr`  and the bottom one is likely the one to look at.  Makes the amount of logs that are likely the one to look at exactly 1. Does not always work sure. But it is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [debmirror](https://linux.die.net/man/1/debmirror) tool to download all the source files. You will pull a lot of files (and we are not talking about a few Gbs here). This will get the source from "main" for "eoan":

```
debmirror -a none --source -s main -d eoan,eoan-security,eoan-updates \
          -r /ubuntu --progress -e http -h archive.ubuntu.com outpath
```

- Replace `main` with `universe`, `multiverse`, and `restricted` to get the other repositories.
- `archive.ubuntu.com` can be any mirror.
- I can not find reliable sources of the size of Ubuntu repositories but [Debian](https://www.debian.org/mirror/size)'s `amd64` is 400Gb. Ubuntu is likely to be not less than that.

[Canonical has provided a script for this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Debmirror) but you will need to adjust this to your needs.